# Does Apache Kafka support LDAP, or is it a Confluent feature?

Tags: security, authentication, apache-kafka, confluent-platform

I am quite new to security with Kafka. Just wondering if Kafka out of the box supports LDAP authentication or is it a confluent feature?

Comment: Are you tied to using confluent or could you use another broker with LDAP native support?

Comment: You could add Apache Ranger to your setup with its Kafka plugin, and set it control LDAP access.

Comment: @TamimiAhmad I am not tied to confluent, just looking for a good method to setup my cluster security atm.

Comment: @OneCricketeer I am actually not across this Apache Ranger thing. Is it opensource? and will it still work as I am not using Hadoop platform or anything special

Comment: Yes it's open source. https://github.com/apache/ranger/tree/master/plugin-kafka You don't need to use its other plugins.

Answer (score 1):

The only authentication Kafka support is

- TLS - Kafka server only communicates with clients having certificate that it trust, basically using TLS for mutual authentication
- SASL using Kerberos - If you are already using Kerberos server like Active Directory you can use it for setting up authentication or set up your own Kerberos server.

http://kafka.apache.org/documentation.html#security_ssl

Comment: There are other SASL options.

Answer (score 1):

Open source Apache Kafka doesn’t include LDAP but it does support LDAP, if that makes sense. Confluent has a proprietary LDAP authentication tool but there is also a free, open source alternative that Instaclustr created. You can access it on GitHub here:
https://github.com/instaclustr/kafka-ldap-integration